# NSObject +load and +initialize - What do they do?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I'm interested in understanding the circumstances leading a developer to override +initialize or +load. Documentation makes it clear these methods are called for you by the Objective-C runtime, but that's really all that is clear from the documentation of those methods. :-)

My curiosity comes from looking at Apple's example code - MVCNetworking. Their model class has a `+(void) applicationStartup` method. It does some housekeeping on the filesystem, reads NSDefaults, etc etc... and, after trying to grok NSObject's class methods, it seems like this janitorial work might be okay to put into +load.

*I did modify the MVCNetworking project, removing the call in App Delegate to +applicationStartup, and putting the housekeeping bits into +load... my computer didn't catch fire, but that doesn't mean it's correct! I'm hoping to gain an understanding of any subtleties, gotchas, and whatnots around a custom setup method you have to call versus +load or +initialize.*

---

For +load documentation says:

> The load message is sent to classes and categories that are both
>   dynamically loaded and statically linked, but only if the newly loaded
>   class or category implements a method that can respond.

This sentence is kludgey and difficult to parse if you don't know the precise meaning of all the words. Help!

- What is meant by "both dynamically loaded and statically linked?" Can something be dynamically loaded AND statically linked, or are they mutually exclusive?
- "...the newly loaded class or category implements a method that can respond" What method? Respond how?

---

As for +initialize, documentation says:

> initialize it is invoked only once per class. If you want to perform
>   independent initialization for the class and for categories of the
>   class, you should implement load methods.

I take this to mean, "if your trying to setup the class... don't use initialize." Okay, fine. When or why would I override initialize then?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

### The `load` message

The runtime sends the `load` message to each class object, very soon after the class object is loaded in the process's address space.  For classes that are part of the program's executable file, the runtime sends the `load` message very early in the process's lifetime.  For classes that are in a shared (dynamically-loaded) library, the runtime sends the load message just after the shared library is loaded into the process's address space.

Furthermore, the runtime only sends `load` to a class object if that class object itself implements the `load` method.  Example:

```
@interface Superclass : NSObject
@end

@interface Subclass : Superclass
@end

@implementation Superclass

+ (void)load {
    NSLog(@"in Superclass load");
}

@end

@implementation Subclass

// ... load not implemented in this class

@end
```

The runtime sends the `load` message to the `Superclass` class object.  It does *not* send the `load` message to the `Subclass` class object, even though `Subclass` inherits the method from `Superclass`.

The runtime sends the `load` message to a class object after it has sent the `load` message to all of the class's superclass objects (if those superclass objects implement `load`) and all of the class objects in shared libraries you link to.  But you don't know which other classes in your own executable have received `load` yet.

Every class that your process loads into its address space will receive a `load` message, if it implements the `load` method, regardless of whether your process makes any other use of the class.

You can see how the runtime looks up the `load` method as a special case in the `_class_getLoadMethod` of [`objc-runtime-new.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm), and calls it directly from `call_class_loads` in [`objc-loadmethod.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-loadmethod.mm).

The runtime also runs the `load` method of every category it loads, even if several categories on the same class implement `load`.  This is unusual.  Normally, if two categories define the same method on the same class, one of the methods will “win” and be used, and the other method will never be called.

### The `initialize` Method

The runtime calls the `initialize` method on a class object just before sending the first message (other than `load` or `initialize`) to the class object or any instances of the class.  This message is sent using the normal mechanism, so if your class doesn't implement `initialize`, but inherits from a class that does, then your class will use its superclass's `initialize`.  The runtime will send the `initialize` to all of a class's superclasses first (if the superclasses haven't already been sent `initialize`).

Example:

```
@interface Superclass : NSObject
@end

@interface Subclass : Superclass
@end

@implementation Superclass

+ (void)initialize {
    NSLog(@"in Superclass initialize; self = %@", self);
}

@end

@implementation Subclass

// ... initialize not implemented in this class

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Subclass *object = [[Subclass alloc] init];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints two lines of output:

```
2012-11-10 16:18:38.984 testApp[7498:c07] in Superclass initialize; self = Superclass
2012-11-10 16:18:38.987 testApp[7498:c07] in Superclass initialize; self = Subclass
```

Since the system sends the `initialize` method lazily, a class won't receive the message unless your program actually sends messages to the class (or a subclass, or instances of the class or subclasses).  And by the time you receive `initialize`, every class in your process should have already received `load` (if appropriate).

The canonical way to implement `initialize` is this:

```
@implementation Someclass

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [Someclass class]) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

The point of this pattern is to avoid `Someclass` re-initializing itself when it has a subclass that doesn't implement `initialize`.

The runtime sends the `initialize` message in the `_class_initialize` function in [`objc-initialize.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-initialize.mm).  You can see that it uses `objc_msgSend` to send it, which is the normal message-sending function.

### Further reading

Check out [Mike Ash's Friday Q&A](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html) on this topic.

Comment: You should note that `+load` is sent separately for categories; that is, every category on a class may contain its own `+load` method.

Comment: Also note that `initialize` will be correctly invoked by a `load` method, if necessary, due to the `load` making reference to the uninitialised entity. This can (oddly, but sensibly) lead to `initialize` running before `load`! That's what I've observed, anyway. This seems to be contrary to "And by the time you receive `initialize`, every class in your process should have already received `load` (if appropriate)."

Comment: You receive `load` first.  You may then receive `initialize` while `load` is still running.

Comment: @Benjohn I have got the same behaviour. Maybe +load is not the direct cause to start +initialize BUT it looks like +initialize called because of +load sent and +initialize runs before +load.

Comment: "And by the time you receive initialize, every class in your process should have already received load (if appropriate)." - this is true. In fact I reproduced the situation when +initialize was _executed_ before +load was. But calling sequence is always first +load message received, than +initialize message received.

Comment: @robmayoff don't we need to add [super initialize] and [super load] lines, inside respective methods ?

Comment: That is usually a bad idea, because the runtime has already sent both of those messages to all of your superclasses before it sends them to you.

Answer (score 17):

What it means is don't override `+initialize` in a category, you'll probably break something.

`+load` is called once per class or category that implements `+load`, *as soon as* that class or category is loaded. When it says "statically linked" it means compiled into your app binary. The `+load` methods on classes thus compiled will be executed when your app launches, probably before it enters `main()`. When it says "dynamically loaded", it means loaded via plugin bundles or a call to `dlopen()`. If you're on iOS, you can ignore that case.

`+initialize` is called the first time a message is sent to the class, just before it handles that message. This (obviously) only happens once. If you override `+initialize` in a category, one of three things will happen:

- your category implementation gets called and the class's implementation doesn't
- someone else's category implementation gets called; nothing you wrote does
- your category hasn't been loaded yet and its implementation never gets called.

This is why you should never override `+initialize` in a category - in fact it's quite dangerous to try and replace *any* method in a category because you're never sure what you're replacing or whether your own replacement will itself be switched out by another category.

BTW, another issue to consider with `+initialize` is that if someone subclasses you, you'll potentially get called once for your class and once for each subclass. If you're doing something like setting up `static` variables, you'll want to guard against that: either with `dispatch_once()` or by testing `self == [MyClass class]`.